# form validation error message

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, authentication

I get this error message when I want to validate username field :

> Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.

For email field is_unique rule goes ok but when I use this rule for username field I get above error 
I use Ion_Auth Authentication library and username and email fields both exist in 'users' table

Validation for username field (I get error message)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'lang:username', 'required|is_unique[users.username]');
```

Validation for email field (OK)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'lang:email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

Comment: did you check the language file to make sure there is a "username" error there?

Comment: This is in ion_auth lang file : $lang['account_creation_duplicate_username']   = 'Username Already Used or Invalid';

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required|is_unique[users.username]');
```